# Why does this conversion error occur for function?

Tags: c++, function, templates, callback, type-conversion

I define a structure to define a type.

```
namespace ns
{
    template <typename T>
    struct StructureForType
    {
        typedef void (*TYPE)(Input<T>);
    };
};
```

In another file, I make these functions.

```
namespace ns
{
    template <typename T1, typename T2, SomeClass<T1, T2> &someclass>
    void TheFunction(Input<T1> input)
    {
        someclass.DoSomething(input);
    }

    template <typename T1, typename T2>
    SomeClass<T1, T2>::SomeClass()
    {
        typename StructureForType<T1>::TYPE func = TheFunction<T1, T2, *this>;
        Input<T1>::SetSomeCallBackFunc(func);
    }

};
```

Then the error occurs in this line :

```
StructureForType<T1>::TYPE func = TheFunction<T1, T2, *this>;
```

> error C2440 'overloaded-function' to 'void (__cdecl *)(ns::Input)'

What should I do?

---

The original code

```
template <typename T>
struct CBDestroyHandleType
{
    typedef void (*TYPE)(CHandle<T> handle);
};


template <typename TAG, typename DATA, CHandleMgr<TAG, DATA> &handleMgr>
void AdaptedDestroyHandle(CHandle<TAG> handle)
{
    handleMgr.CBDestroyHandle(handle);
}


template <typename TAG, typename DATA>
CHandleMgr<TAG, DATA>::CHandleMgr()
{
    CBDestroyHandleType<TAG>::TYPE cbFunc = AdaptedDestroyHandle<TAG, DATA, *this>;
    CHandle<TAG>::SetCBDestroyHandle(cbFunc);
}
```

Error in this line : CBDestroyHandleType::TYPE cbFunc = AdaptedDestroyHandle;

error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'void (__cdecl *)(res::CHandle)' to 'void (__cdecl *)(res::CHandle)'

Comment: I don't believe this is the first error you have listed

Comment: For callbacks to member functions in C++, I suggest you read about [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) and [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind), or their Boost equivalents.

Comment: 1. `SomeClass::SomeClass()` should be `SomeClass<T1, T2>::SomeClass()`, 2. `StructureForType<T1>::TYPE func` should be `typename StructureForType<T1>::TYPE func`, not to mention other issues

Comment: You should probably make the reference `SomeClass<T1, T2> &someclass` part of the function's argument.

Comment: that is just my mistake. Original code has just this error

Comment: @SnowInnocent: please copy-paste the actual code that triggers the error

Comment: I don't believe `TheFunction<T1, T2, *this>` is a valid expression.

Comment: Why isn't it a valid expression?

Comment: @SnowInnocent: post http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that at least triggers the error you see